# Swift - Scroll View smaller than Main View

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I've many troubles with a `ScrollView` that is more little than main view.

My goal is the layout in the figure

[image: Goal]

where gray view is a `TableView` and blue is a hierarchy composed by a `View` inside the `ScrollView`. Everything is plaed all inside a main `View`. So the general hierarchy is the follow

[image: hierarchy]

In the `ScrollView` i've to put many elements, `Switch` for the final product, `Label` to understand. So i want the possibility to scroll.

Reading around the web i've found always the same, more or less, solution, this: [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnQsFlMGDsI), [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_rVXhbBfFjo), [three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhhW3xqhCzg), [four](https://medium.com/disblu/scroll-view-auto-layout-in-xcode-8-7f43e82fe33), [five](https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7), etc.

As soon as i add various constraints as explained (for me are not all 0), both on the emulator and on the real device, the `ScrollView` disappears.

But as we see, in these example there is the case of a single `ScrollView` inside a main `View`, on full display. So i've tried also with another `View` to contain the hierarchy `ScrollView`-`View`. Unfortunately, i've the same results.

What is the problem? Where wrong i?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control-drag from the content view of the scrollView to the viewControllers view and make Equal widths then change that constraint multiplier to 0.5 , same for the tableView sure minue margin between it and the scrollview

also make sure constraints are properly hooked from top to bottom

Here is a demo of what you want exactly [scrollViewHalf](https://github.com/ShKhan9/scrollViewHalf)